# Material Ui 3 with only less styling

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I'm using Material ui 3 with react js and wondering how to get Less styling for components. I know that Material UI uses JSS. But what is the right way to do it with less.

I want styling like this:

```
.component{
   color: "red",
   .subComponent:{
      color: "blue"
   }
}
```

Is the JSS best way to do it? Or can I use only less?

Answer (score 0):

you have to do the {this.props.classes.className} for className of your element and don't put dot in the first of the class name but before all of that you should setup the jss and wrap your component with injectSheet function from jss itself